# Dispatch Excel to different SharePoint lists based on Department field

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have Excel sheet representing a survey that shall be dispatched to different departments (based on one department field). How can this be done with the help of SharePoint? Note that each department can only see the result (charts) pertinent to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could host the Excel file in non-searchable document library and create some chart web parts that relate to different department.

This can't be done with a full security based on the excel contents, so if you want to have full security you must create multiple files.